# Copiar archivos y directorios con gulp.js

Tags: javascript, gulp

Estoy usando el gestor de tareas **gulp.js** en mi proyecto de AngularJS y Django.

Debido a la configuración de mi repositorio git, el directorio de estáticos, llamado `assets` no se controla, por lo que tengo un directorio, `sources`, donde están los archivos fuentes.

Estoy haciendo una tarea para copiar estoy archivos (inicialmente sin procesar, comprimir, etc.) a la carpeta `assets` haciendo esto:

```
// Configuración
var config = {
  sourcesDir: './sources',
  bowerDir: './bower_components'     
}

// tarea fuentes
gulp.task('fuentes', function(){
  gulp.src([config.sourcesDir + '/css/styles.css'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css'));
});
```

Es decir, un solo archivo se mueve del origen `src`al destino `dest` sin problemas.

Mi problema es que estoy haciendo los servicios de angular con la misma estructura de Django y tengo varios directorios con uno o mas archivos dentro de una carpeta javascript, asi:

```
js
├── auth
├── cmi.js
├── indicadores
│   ├── encuestas
│   └── productividad
├── inecap
└── metas
```

**Pregunta:** ¿Como configuro mi tarea `fuentes` para que copie los archivos `js` y la estructura del origen  `[config.sourcesDir + '/js']` en el destino `./assets/js`?

Comment: toledano veo que usted cambio la pregunta, pero dese cuenta que si la cambia las respuetas podrian quedar como malas, en este caso mi respuesta, pues ahora pide que solo sea .js, y a antes queria todos, le acabo de dejar unos ejemplos, pero tenga cuidado con esas ediciones y mas cuando ahi respuestas en base a la pregunta original, no se lo tome a mal. Saludos

Comment: Tienes razón, @AngelAngel. Gracias por hacérmelo notar. Tendré más cuidado con las ediciones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puede probar con esto:

Para todos:

```
gulp.task('copy', function () {
        gulp.src([config.sourcesDir + '/js'+'/**/*'])
          .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/js));
    });
```

Para solo el tipo que se le indica(ejemplo con .js):

```
gulp.task('copy', function () {
            gulp.src([config.sourcesDir + '/js'+'/**/*.js'])
              .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/js));
        });
```

ejemplos:

- **js/**/*.js** coincide con los archivos que terminen en `.js` dentro
  del directorio `js` y dentro de todas las sub-carpetas de este.
- **js/suDirectorioSource/exactamente.js** coincide exactamente con el archivo.
- **js/suDirectorioSource/*.js** coincide con los archivos que terminen en `.js` dentro
  de la carpeta `js/suDirectorioSource`.
- **!js/suDirectorioSource/excluir.js** excluye especificamente el archivo `excluir.js` con el uso de <kbd>!</kbd>
- **Source/*.+(js|css)** coincide con los archivos que terminen en `.js` o
  `.css` dentro del direcorio `Source/`

Comment: Funcionó! Me di cuenta que en realidad no quería copiar toda la estructura sino solo los archivos `js`, pero el ajuste es insignificante. Gracias

Comment: @toledano te deje algunos ejemplos a raiz de tu comentario. Saludos